# User groups, and dififerent views / functions for each group

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

**Desired Output:**
Employee and Client user types. If registering through the main website the user will automatically be a Client. Client type users get a different menu/dashboard/portal whatever you wanna call that. For examples. Clients can book an appointment. Then for employees that usertype is set manually in django admin. AFterwards when they log in, they get a different dashboard, say  one that displays their schedule and they can put available hours. This user doesnt even need to have a registration page it can all be done in admin.

From my limited understanding to bring this desired outcome to reality I must extend the userprofile? Or should I entirely create a custom userprofile using the AbstractUser abstraction?

Also where does django groups come in. And is all this User model extending even necessary? Can django groups be used entirely for this project?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #define general fields

class Client(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    #freelancer specific  fields

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Client'

class Employee(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    #Employee specific fields 

   class Meta:
        db_table = 'Employee'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default django groups

---

in your views.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# for inscription register the right group
def inscription(request):
    g = Group.objects.get(name='client')
    user = User()
    "etc"
    user.groups.add(g)
    user.save()
    
#To login
def loggedPage(request):
    userGroup = Group.objects.get(user=request.user).name
    if userGroup == 'client':
         "do some stuff"
    elif userGroup == 'employee':
         "do some other stuff"
```

WARNING: you have to register 2 groups with

> python manage.py shell

one called *employee* and the other *client*

You can also use management to initialize your db with the right groups:
create a file called *yourapp/management/commands/DB_init.py* (create folders if doesn't exists, and write this in it:

```py
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "YOURAPP.settings"
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import  Group


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="client")
        if created:
            group.name = "client"
            group.save()

        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="employee")
        if created:
            group.name = "employee"
            group.save()
```

If you have created folders, think to put an "__ init __.py" in them to transform them as python packages.

your files should look like this:

```py
YOURAPP/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            DB_init.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Run

*python manage.py DB_init*

and voila !

Comment: So say i'd like to have the clients to have an address field, and the employees don't have an address field but instead have a phone number, or hours worked. How should that be dealt with? Should I just extend a user model which has all those fields and some are used depending on the group of the user? Or should i create 2 custom user profiles that each have their respective attributes?

Comment: both are valid, so i will say 'it depend', I suggest you to just extend a user model with a profil model (linked with one to one field to your user model), and do what you want in your view depending of the group

Comment: So like in my code sample but instead of ForeignKey to use OneToOneField?

Comment: hum seems over complicated, why don't just use a profile model with phone number, adresse, etc... and link that to the User? you don't need to have 2 models for client / employee, they are users, with the group you will know what kind of users they are